# How to input text in android app without it displaying on the screen?

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I would like to make an app which requires me to enter text without it being displayed on the screen. I don't even want it in the password format (i.e. *****). I had an idea to receive the text from another phone from the internet or bluetooth but I don't know if that is possible? If yes could you guide me how to start?? Any help would be appreciated.

PS:Let me know if my question is not making sense :P. I'll follow up and try to explain it better. 
Thanks

I am making a game of Peter answers and i want to input some text without others standing nearby knowing what I am doing. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: Your question isn't making sense.

Comment: What do you want to do with this text? Will this be a "super-secret" way of logging into an app? My best guess is using a transparent EditText where the text color matches the background.  Regardless I like seeing the text I'm typing on soft keyboards because I'm prone to making typos...

Comment: No not really. It's pretty basic, like you ask others to enter a q and then enter the answer without there knowledge. Yeah guess I could do that. Btw is it possible that when i type the answer it doesnt show up on the input text but another predefined string such as "Plz give us the answer" or something comes up. This way i could enter the answer and people would not know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try having a button that will select a hidden (Actually hidden or covered by something else) TextView and then when they type, because the TextView is hidden, the text will not be displayed. After that, you can always copy the text and clear the TextView just so no glitches allow the text to be seen.

I think the biggest issue though would be selecting hidden TextView. If you want it to look like they are selecting a visible TextView, you could always do the same thing you would do with a button, but just when the TextView is selected.

Comment: Yeah I guess that could be done. But how do I clear an element and how do I sell to the other person that I am not typing it in?Like they will see me typing into the keyboard right? I was thinking if the enter text could show a predefined string when someone writes the answer ?? But I dont really know how to go about this.

Comment: How did you plan to type without a keyboard? If you want predefined text to be entered without someone who is looking over your shoulder seeing that you are entering it, you could use the hardware buttons such as volume buttons to enter the desired text. If you have more than 2 texts to be input, try using discreet dots or a discreet number that the volume buttons can rotate through. Then the user would just have to know what each one represents.

Comment: No what I am trying to say is that if i write in something like "Your name is ______" The keyboard will show that I am writing "Please answer my question?". This is starting to not seem like a good idea. I'll probably do something else.

Comment: Oh. yeah you can have it automatically type that in when you are actually editing text in another hidden TextView. So you type in "Johnathon Smith" and as you type that, the visible TextView types in "Please answer my question?" or whatever you want. So, set it up to know when you enter one character and enter one predefined character. That way, when you type 'J' it displays 'P' and then 'o' displays 'l' and so on. So, when you enter character x, predefined character x will display. It won't match up perfectly, but you can play with holding the volume button to actually enter text or not.

Comment: Thanks :D That seems like something which can be done? Just one more thing can you point me to an article or page which will help me execute the abovementioned? I am new to android so don't really know what to search. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Well a lot of it will just be custom java code. At least the entering one letter as you enter one. For the hidden TextView just search in google: "Android hidden TextView" and you will find a page on that. Generally you can just search "Android [question/search] [example(optional)]" 
I generally search like this and filter through for what I want and click on stackoverflow pages for the examples.

Comment: Thank you very much . I will get to it. :D

Comment: Be sure to select this answer since it helped so it will boost my reputation on stackoverflow. I'm assuming you're new to this site as well.

Comment: Yeah did not know that. Cheers. Oh turns out i can select the green arrow but cannot vote up due to <15 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

I once did a mistake and was wondering why wasn't anything typing in the EditText, until I realized that my Text color was same as the EditText background, namely white. Try this one, but the cursor will move forward though.